# Which config file is fit for my example to config apache2?

Tags: apache-httpd, dns

Let's suppose a scene.

- domain name:  xyz.com
- the domain parsed by third-party dns server:   ns1.xxx.com
- IP address bound with domain:  123.123.123.123
- apache2 was installed on  123.123.123.123

Should my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf be this way :

```
config1:

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerName 123.123.123.123:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

config2:  

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerName xyz.com:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

config3:  

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerName localhost:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>

config4:  

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.xyz.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Which config file is fit for my example?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache's ServerName Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) performs the same basic function as [nginx's server_name directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name), that is, it is compared against the `Host` parameter in the incoming HTTP request, if it matches that virtual host config is chosen. Importantly it is only used for selection of the virtual host - if the webserver can't resolve the request by the port or IP address of the network interface the webserver is listening on - i.e.  `ServerName` is only used for the selection of the virtual host if this `<VirtualHost *:80>` doesn't unambiguously resolve to a virtual host/config.

From the docs

> Description:  Hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself
>   Syntax:   ServerName [scheme://]domain-name|ip-address[:port]

Per your example the ServerName directive would be used in an Apache virtual host config like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName xyz.com
  ...
  ...
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have changed my question to make it more clearly.